# Invoking 3rd party APIs via Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, httprequest, custom-activity

We intend to use the Journey Builder of the Salesforce Marketing Cloud in order to invoke a 3rd party HTTP-based API.
As far as I can tell, our only viable option is following the guidelines of: [Build Custom Activities and Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm)

Is that still valid ? Is there any alternative we are missing ?

What about the [REST Custom Activity](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/rest.htm) ?
That seems an even more straight-forward way to invoke a REST API but it's unclear from the documentation if there are any prerequisites on the Journey Builder side that we should take into account.

Comment: Does this call need to happen in real time?

Comment: @LukasLunow yes, the invocation should be part of the Journey execution